# This code runs in WATIR-Classic but not in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

```
require 'watir'
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'www.xyz.com'
b.maximize
b.label(:text, "Car Make").parent.spans[1].click
b.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: "BMW").when_present.click
```

The above code works fine when I write for watir-classic, but when I write above code for watir-webdriver, the visibility checking is stopping me to click `b.label(:text, "Car Make").parent.spans[1].click` this element, Is there any way Can I cancel out this visibility checking in watir webdriver? The code which I have written for watir-webdriver follows,

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-scroll'
b=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'www.xyz.com'
b.window.maximize
b.label(:text, "Car Make").parent.spans[1].click
b.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: "BMW").when_present.click
```

Comment: at one point, watir was 1 based for indexes, but we moved to 0 based.  Just to be sure that's not it.. you are trying to click the second span below the parent, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in Watir-Webdriver for disabling the visibility checks. For testing, it is actually better that you do not interact with non-visible elements.

The best solution is really to make the label/span visible before you click it. Perhaps you just need to wait for it to be present:

```
b.label(:text, "Car Make").parent.spans[1].when_present.click
```

If you really do want to bypass the visibility check, you could fire the click event directly. Note that you may need to fire multiple events if your element is expecting more than just a click:

```
b.label(:text, "Car Make").parent.spans[1].fire_event(:onclick)
```

Comment: The visibility thing is baked into webdriver btw, not watir.  ALL tools that sit on top of webdriver (selenium, capybara, watir, etc) will have that same restriction on interacting with elements that are not visible to the user.

Comment: Other place I tried fire_event but it's not click is not clicking. The tag is `<div class="quote-widget" id="quote-widget" ng-controller="getAQuotePopupController">
    <div class="quote-widget-tabs">
  <a style="" class="selected" href="" data-masthead="car" ng-click="displayQuoteWidgetForm('car');" ng-class="(displayedQuoteForm=='car') ? 'selected' : ''">Car <span>Insurance</span></a> 
  <a style="" class="" href="" data-masthead="travel" ng-click="displayQuoteWidgetForm('travel');" ng-class="(displayedQuoteForm=='travel') ? 'selected' : ''"Travel>` (follows next)

Comment: continuation from above `<span>Insurance</span></a> 
    </div>
</div>
$browser.div(:id,"quote-widget").div.as[1].fire_event(:click)` 

Can you please suggest me what kind of problem this could be?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without seeing the page and/or related JavaScript. However, I have seen some controls that expected more than just being clicked. For example, one autocomplete I was working with required the focus event to be triggered before the click event. Ultimately, you need to dig into the JavaScript and determine what events are triggered when the user interacts with it.

Comment: @JustinKo Okay Thank you.